# how does the stitch tool work?

Tags: uv

i'm teaching myself UV mapping in blender, and i assumed the stitch tool worked similarly to the sew tool in maya, where if you select an edge and hit sew (or, more likely, move and sew) and it joins the UV edges together. that's how the documentation made it sound. but when i try it, my uv island moves but the edges don't join together. what am i doing wrong? is there a different tool that does this, or am i using the tool wrong somehow? i'm having a hard time finding documentation of how to use specific tools.

i'm using industry compatible keybindings so please use tool names instead of just hotkeys, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Stitch tool is a modal operator, meaning when you run the operator, you enter a temporary state where you have to interact with the tool to fine tune its effect before validating it with <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or canceling with <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.
You can see the different things you can do while in a modal operator in the [Status Bar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/status_bar.html):

[image: status bar in Stitch operator]

After validating the stitching, you can still access its settings in the [Adjust Last Operation panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#bpy-ops-screen-redo-last). Be aware though that this panel shows the settings of the last operation. If you do anything else, it will switch to that latest action.